# Link in excel different workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created an Excel file with formulas and links. I want to copy it to different workbooks with different names and I want the data to be updated automatically. Example: workbook name: Test.xls 
Sheet names: Sheet1, Sheet2

Cell A1 in Sheet1 reads: 999 
In cell A5 in Sheet2, I have linked it to cell A1 in Sheet1 and it reads: ='Sheet1'!A1

Now I want to copy this link to another workbook, e.g. FINAL.xls

In workbook FINAL.xls, there are 2 sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2 In cell A1 in Sheet1, value is 777. When I copy the formula in Sheet2 cell A5, it is linked to workbook Test.xls.

I want it to display what's in Workbook FINAL.xls cell A1.

Can this link automatically be linked to the new workbook?

What I want to achieve is that in whatever Workbook I paste the formula/link, it should give result of that Workbook. There should be no link with the initial workbook.

Comment: You have used the word new workbook. How do we know which workbook is new? Please replace it with Test or Final.xls

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear of your question. But I suppose you want to do is link a cell to another cell in another workbook. Kindly tell if I am wrong and I will update my answer.

`='C:\Users\Bhavish\Documents\[Final.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

Simply change the file path in above example.

Comment: Can we not write the part, ='C:\Users\Bhavish\Documents\ ?  Whatever the name of the workbook and its location, when i copy the initial formula, i want it to display result of the new workbook in the new workbook. Thank you

Comment: Whatever name of the workbook, when i copy the link/formula, the result must give data from the new workbook.

Comment: You can have the `='C:\Users\Bhavish\Documents\` portion in a separate cell (non-print or otherwise hidden if preferred), which you can then use =INDIRECT() to reference formulaically.  This assumes that all the relevant sources you are referencing will be saved to that exact path, otherwise you may need to setup multiple reference cells.